# Can't get metrics on specific k8s nodes

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

I have the following problem:
I observed that the "kubectl top po " does not provide metrics. More specific I get:
Error from server (NotFound): podmetrics.metrics.k8s.io"pod name"not found
What I checked:

1. I checked if the "kubectl top node" commands and works propelry
2. "kubectl top pod" doesn't work for pods that are deployed in a specific k8s nodes.
   I give : kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes//proxy/stats/summary
   and I observed that for some K8s nodes I see "pods": []

3.Finally metric-server is up and running
In the logs I see "unable to fetch pod metrics for pod : no metrics known for pod "
I think that is a K8s nodes problem, not metrics-server
Any idea what else I can check in the problematic nodes?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? How did you deployed metrics servers? Where are you running this (kubeadm, minikube?) Which kubernetes version?

Comment: kuberentes version 1.13 , I am using kubeadm and I have deployed metricserver:    --cert-dir=/cert
      --secure-port=xxxx
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
      --kubelet-use-node-status-port
      --kubelet-insecure-tls
      --v=2
      --authorization-always-allow-paths=/livez,/readyz